# SQL Server - report error back to .NET

Tags: .net, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using Entity Framework with stored procedures for inserting/updating/deleting entities.

The task that I'm doing is inventory management with FIFO/LIFO methods => those inserts/updates/deletes perform several checks and can fail (sometimes they fail).

The problem is I want to report back to .NET what went wrong and why. How can I do it?

Currently I'm using something like this:

```
BEGIN --rollback
ROLLBACK TRAN
RAISERROR (N'There''s not enough items in stock.', -- message
    16, -- severity
    1) -- state
END;
```

I always get "MSDTC error" - "The underlying provider failed on EnlistTransaction."

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is getting that far. It is erroring out when one of the transactions is starting up, your custom error is not getting raised.

Comment: That's probably the case. The problem is that if everything is OK then the transaction commits fine -> my error handling causes something to break. I suppose that the flow of execution in the SP is not interrupted and when it reaches COMMIT everything breaks (as it should, because the transaction has already been rolled back). E tity Framework reports the last error -> it's not mine..

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check the InnerException to get the custom error you have raised.